# Low information density (icons too sparse) in Nautilus on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, nautilus

Information density in Nautilus on Ubuntu 13.04 is way too low for me; i.e. too few lines fits on the screen to my liking.

For example, here's the same directory displayed in Nautilus in Ubuntu 12.04 (ok):
http://i298.photobucket.com/albums/mm249/hrenistic/nautilus_800x600_u1204_zps447df9e4.png

and in Ubuntu 13.04 (way too sparse):
http://i298.photobucket.com/albums/mm249/hrenistic/nautilus_800x600_u1304_zpsa4484a78.png

How do I make Nautilus display files in a more compact mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Open Nautilus and Click on the menu and select Preferences

[image]

Comment: Looks like 'List View Defaults' is what I need, thanks! I think I'll go with 33%, this is even more compact than in 12.04. Could have used more options, but oh well, the ones that they have (50% and 33%) are usable.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance, if the answer helped, could you up-vote it and if it fixed your problem, give it a tick :)

Comment: Of course! I just waited a bit to see if even more useful answer will show up before voting.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Nautilus developer removed some features in nautilus 3.6, which is included by default in Ubuntu 13.04, now nautilus 3.6 unsupported to compact view, but we can add it from using nautilus 3.4 patched version, run this command in terminal to get older features

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/experiments
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
killall nautilus
```

Comment: What is this "compact view" that was removed? I'm not sure if I was using it. I am using the one that is switched on by the shortcut 'Ctrl+1'